# php error fix accepting 0 or null in while

Tags: php, arrays

I have this while that goes through an array

```
while($value = current($array)){
    $fields.=key($array);
    $val.=$value;
    next($array);
}
```

So the problem is that when I set one of the array argument to 0 or null, the while stops...

How can I fix it, so it can add the 0 or null arguments in string?

Comment: Why aren't you using a foreach loop? or using `implode(array_keys($array))` and `implode($array)`?

Comment: If `$value = current($array)` returns a falsey value like 0 or null, then it will stop; that's to be expected because while is intended to stop when not truthy.... use a `foreach()` or `implode()` as @mickmackusa has suggested

Comment: ok, foreach works fine, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can safely use either of these alternative methods:

```
$array=['a','b','c'];
$fields='';
$val='';
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $fields.=$key;
    $val.=$value;
}
```

or

```
$fields=implode(array_keys($array));
$val=implode($array);
```

[Simple demonstration](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/64a1e215cbcec16bc7a2fe9319bedd3d5518e945)

---

---

Now, I don't recommend what is to follow, but if you are definitely not holding any `false` (strictly false I mean) values, you can use this "fix":

```
$array=['a','0','c',null,'e','f','g',0,'i'];
$fields='';
$val='';
while(($value=current($array))!==false){
    $fields.=key($array);
    $val.=$value;  // null values (0-length strings) vanish during concatenation
    next($array);
}
echo "$fields\n$val";
```

Output:

```
012345678
a0cefg0i
```

This gets you around the type-based flaw in your original code.